# Regex Latin characters filter and non latin character filer

Tags: c#, regex, ascii, non-ascii-characters

I am developing a program ,where I need to filter words and sentences which are non-Latin character. The problem is, that I found only Latin character words and sentences , but I do not found words and sentences which are mixed with Latin characters and non-Latin characters. For example, "Hello" is Latin letter word, and I can match it using this code:

```
Match match = Regex.Match(line.Line, @"[^\u0000-\u007F]+", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);

if (match.Success)
{
    line.Line = match.Groups[1].Value;
}
```

But I do not found for example mixed with non-Latin letter word or sentences : "Hellø I am sømthing" .

Also, could somebody explain what is RegexOptions.None or RegexOptions.IgnoreCase and for what they stand for?

Comment: I always considered `àèéìòù` to be latin...

Comment: And that regular expression **won't** find `Hello`, because it will find only characters that are > 0x7F, so it will fine an `ø`

Comment: @xanatos Indeed. Unicode describes è as LATIN SMALL LETTER E WITH GRAVE. So, BinaryTie, do you want to include or exclude such latin characters?

Comment: @TomBlodget . Yes I want that it will be included non Latin characters. 
I just need to filter all words which contain non Latin characters in words. It can be only non Latin characters or it could be mixed Latin characters with  non Latin characters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The four "Latin" blocks are (from http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/index.htm):

> Basic Latin U+0000 - U+007F
>
> Latin-1 Supplement U+0080 - U+00FF
>
> Latin Extended-A U+0100 - U+017F
>
> Latin Extended-B U+0180 - U+024F

So a Regex to "include" all of them would be:

```
Regex.Match(line.Line, @"[\u0000-\u024F]+", RegexOptions.None);
```

while a Regex to catch anything outside the block would be:

```
Regex.Match(line.Line, @"[^\u0000-\u024F]+", RegexOptions.None);
```

Note that I do feel that doing a regex "by block" is a little wrong, especially when you use the Latin blocks, because for example in the Basic Latin block you have control characters (like new line, ...), letters (A-Z, a-z), numbers (0-9), punctation (.,;:...), other characters ($@/&...) and so on.

For the meaning of `RegexOptions.None` and `RegexOptions.IgnoreCase`

- Their name is quite clear
- you could try googling them on MSDN

From https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regexoptions.aspx:

> RegexOptions.None: Specifies that no options are set
>
> RegexOptions.IgnoreCase: Specifies case-insensitive matching.

the last one means that if you do `Regex.Match(line.Line, @"ABC", RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)` it will match `ABC`, `Abc`, `abc`, ... And this option works even on character ranges like `[A-Z]` that will match both `A-Z` and `a-z`. Note that it is probably useless in this case because the blocks I suggested should contain both the uppercase and the lowercase "variation" of letters that are both uppercase and lowercase.