# Match alphanumeric characters, including latin unicode

Tags: c#, regex

I have a working regex that matches ASCII alphanumeric characters:

```
 string pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9]+$";
 Match match = Regex.Match(input, pattern);
 if (match.Success)
 {
   ...
```

I want to extend this to apply the same concept, but include all latin characters (e.g. å, Ø etc).

I've read about [unicode scripts](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html). And I've tried this:

```
 string pattern = "^[{Latin}0-9]+$";
```

But it's not matching the patterns I expect. How do I match latin unicode using unicode scripts or an alternative method?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Regex Latin characters filter and non latin character filer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29948341/regex-latin-characters-filter-and-non-latin-character-filer)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `^[\p{L}\s]+$` to match any unicode character

Or `^[\w\u00c0-\u017e]$` to match any letter plus unicode characters from 00c0 to 017e (use charmap to find unicode characters range you need)

[Sample on regex101](https://regex101.com/r/7qWBWB/2/)

Comment: @mtmacdonald You either need to use [verbatim strings](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16635176/what-is-a-verbatim-string) (`@"..."`) or escape the backslashes.

Comment: @stej4n Why is that the ASCII alpha characters are included in the match in your second example, when they are below the range 00C0?

Comment: Because I add \w which match ASCII chars

Answer (score 5):

Unicode scripts are not supported by .NET regex engine but Unicode blocks are. Having that said, you are able to match all latin characters using below regex:

```
^[\p{IsBasicLatin}\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}\p{IsLatinExtended-A}\p{IsLatinExtended-B}0-9]+$
```

- `\p{IsBasicLatin}`: U+0000–U+007F
- `\p{IsLatin-1Supplement}`: U+0080–U+00FF
- `\p{IsLatinExtended-A}`: U+0100–U+017F
- `\p{IsLatinExtended-B}`: U+0180–U+024F

or simply use `^[\u0000-\u024F0-9]+$`.

Mentioned by [@AnthonyFaull](https://stackoverflow.com/users/63264/anthony-faull) you may want to consider matching `\p{IsLatinExtendedAdditional}` as well which is a named block for U+1E00-U+1EFF that contains 256 additional characters:

```
[ắẮằẰẵẴẳẲấẤầẦẫẪẩẨảẢạ ẠặẶậẬḁḀ ẚ ḃḂḅḄḇḆ ḉḈ ḋḊḑḐḍḌḓḒḏḎ ẟ ếẾềỀễỄểỂẽẼḝḜḗḖḕḔẻẺẹẸ ệỆḙḘḛḚ ḟḞ ḡḠ ḧḦḣḢḩḨḥḤḫḪẖ ḯḮỉỈịỊḭḬ ḱḰḳḲḵḴ ḷḶḹḸḽḼḻḺ ỻỺ ḿḾṁṀṃṂ ṅṄṇṆṋṊṉṈ ốỐồỒỗỖổỔṍṌṏṎṓṒṑṐỏỎớỚ ờỜỡỠởỞợỢọỌộỘ ṕṔṗṖ ṙṘṛṚṝṜṟṞ ṥṤṧṦṡṠṣṢṩṨẛ ẞ ẜ ẝ ẗṫṪṭṬṱṰṯṮ ṹṸṻṺủỦứỨừỪữỮửỬựỰụỤṳṲ ṷṶṵṴ ṽṼṿṾ ỽỼ ẃẂẁẀẘẅẄẇẆẉẈ ẍẌẋẊ ỳỲẙỹỸẏẎỷỶỵỴ ỿỾ ẑẐẓẒẕẔ]
```

Comment: Great answer. You may wish to add `\p{IsLatinExtendedAdditional}`.

Comment: @AnthonyFaull Thank you. Added.

Answer (score 1):

I will use unicode scripts.

As describe by Wikipedia (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Latin_script_in_Unicode), I will use Latin-1 Supplement (00C0-00FF), Latin Extended-A (0100–017F), Latin Extended-B (0180–024F) and your pattern for ASCII alphanumeric characters.

```
string pattern = "^[a-zA-Z0-9\\u00C0–\\u024F]+$";
```

Comment: 123Æ is not matching?