# Regex allow only Uppercase Extended ASCII

Tags: regex

I need a regex to allow only Uppercase Extended ASCII characters of a **maxLength** I set before that it's the maximum length of the word.

Regex for uppercase letters: **\P{Ll}***

Regex for extended ASCII letters: **[\x00-\xFF]***

Using ^[\p{Ll}] it's not enough because I need characters to be extended ASCII(to not allow emoji or other special characters outrange ASCII extended).

How can I combine that 2 requirements ? And length of **maxLength**.

Thank you!!

Comment: Maybe `^[\p{Latin}&&\p{Lu}]{1,10}$` / `^(?:(?=\p{Lu})\p{Latin}){1,10}$` will work? Like all Latin letters that are uppercase letters, one to ten occurrences?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew The latter seems to work, the former doesn't (`&&` is just parsed as a literal, not as a boolean operator); I got it to work with a double-negated character class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally, you can use

```js
^(?:(?=\p{Lu})\p{Latin}){1,10}$
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/HtYJhM/1). *Details*:

- `^` - start of string
- `(?:` - start of a non-capturing group:

  - `(?=\p{Lu})\p{Latin}` - a char from `Latin` Unicode category class that is an uppercase letter
- `){1,10}` - end of the group, repeat one to ten occurrences
- `$` - end of string.

Since you are using the regex in a DevExpress masked input component you need to enumerate all these letters in a character class. Based on [Regex Latin characters filter and non latin character filer](https://stackoverflow.com/q/29948341/3832970), you need

> Latin-1 Supplement `U+0080 - U+00FF`
> Latin Extended-A `U+0100 - U+017F`
> Latin Extended-B `U+0180 - U+024F`

All chars that are uppercase letters in these three ranges are the ones you want to allow:

```js
var res = []
for (var i=128; i<=591; i++) {                     // Get chars from \u0080 to \u024F
   if (/^\p{Lu}$/u.test(String.fromCharCode(i))) { // If it is an uppercase letter
     res.push(String.fromCharCode(i));             // Add it to the results
   } 
}
console.log(res.join(""))
```

The code will look like

```cs
settings.MaskExpression = "[\\u00C0-\\u00D6\\u00D8-\\u00DE\\u0100\\u0102\\u0104\\u0106\\u0108\\u010A\\u010C\\u010E\\u0110\\u0112\\u0114\\u0116\\u0118\\u011A\\u011C\\u011E\\u0120\\u0122\\u0124\\u0126\\u0128\\u012A\\u012C\\u012E\\u0130\\u0132\\u0134\\u0136\\u0139\\u013B\\u013D\\u013F\\u0141\\u0143\\u0145\\u0147\\u014A\\u014C\\u014E\\u0150\\u0152\\u0154\\u0156\\u0158\\u015A\\u015C\\u015E\\u0160\\u0162\\u0164\\u0166\\u0168\\u016A\\u016C\\u016E\\u0170\\u0172\\u0174\\u0176\\u0178\\u0179\\u017B\\u017D\\u0181\\u0182\\u0184\\u0186\\u0187\\u0189-\\u018B\\u018E-\\u0191\\u0193\\u0194\\u0196-\\u0198\\u019C\\u019D\\u019F\\u01A0\\u01A2\\u01A4\\u01A6\\u01A7\\u01A9\\u01AC\\u01AE\\u01AF\\u01B1-\\u01B3\\u01B5\\u01B7\\u01B8\\u01BC\\u01C4\\u01C7\\u01CA\\u01CD\\u01CF\\u01D1\\u01D3\\u01D5\\u01D7\\u01D9\\u01DB\\u01DE\\u01E0\\u01E2\\u01E4\\u01E6\\u01E8\\u01EA\\u01EC\\u01EE\\u01F1\\u01F4\\u01F6-\\u01F8\\u01FA\\u01FC\\u01FE\\u0200\\u0202\\u0204\\u0206\\u0208\\u020A\\u020C\\u020E\\u0210\\u0212\\u0214\\u0216\\u0218\\u021A\\u021C\\u021E\\u0220\\u0222\\u0224\\u0226\\u0228\\u022A\\u022C\\u022E\\u0230\\u0232\\u023A\\u023B\\u023D\\u023E\\u0241\\u0243-\\u0246\\u0248\\u024A\\u024C\\u024E]{1,10}";
```

The `\u...` part matches any letters from the `ÀÁÂÃÄÅÆÇÈÉÊËÌÍÎÏÐÑÒÓÔÕÖØÙÚÛÜÝÞĀĂĄĆĈĊČĎĐĒĔĖĘĚĜĞĠĢĤĦĨĪĬĮİĲĴĶĹĻĽĿŁŃŅŇŊŌŎŐŒŔŖŘŚŜŞŠŢŤŦŨŪŬŮŰŲŴŶŸŹŻŽƁƂƄƆƇƉƊƋƎƏƐƑƓƔƖƗƘƜƝƟƠƢƤƦƧƩƬƮƯƱƲƳƵƷƸƼǄǇǊǍǏǑǓǕǗǙǛǞǠǢǤǦǨǪǬǮǱǴǶǷǸǺǼǾȀȂȄȆȈȊȌȎȐȒȔȖȘȚȜȞȠȢȤȦȨȪȬȮȰȲȺȻȽȾɁɃɄɅɆɈɊɌɎ` set.

The `{1,10}` limiting quantifier matches one to ten occurrences. You may adjust it further.

Comment: I highly appreciate your answer. I am just wondering if there is no way  to make the expression from settings.MaskExpression shorter or simpler? And using extended ASCII instead of unicode...

Comment: @bags No, because the regexp flavor you are using is too limited.

Answer (score 1):

Slight modification of @Wiktor's comment that I think is easier to read:

```
^[^\P{Lu}\P{Latin}]{0,10}$
```

should match a string of a max of 10 uppercase Latin (inc. extended) characters. Using a negation class to find 10 characters that are not *not* uppercase nor *not* Latin. It does match such beautiful and definitely not cursed strings as `ĦꜴꝎꞂꜨⱠƎƢƔ`.

Comment: But how can I use it in my code? It says I have syntax errors and I tried this:

           
                    settings.MaskExpression = "^[^\\P{Lu}\\P{Latin}]{0,10}$";

And still have syntax errors

Comment: @bags What language or app are you using this in? It's possible the language uses a regex engine that doesn't recognize the \P{Latin} token. If it's not that, I don't know what to tell you since you literally haven't shown any code that would reveal a syntax error. I do know though that this regex pattern should work in JS, Python, or anything that uses PCRE.